# JavaFX: Listen for position changes of a node

Tags: java, properties, javafx, javafx-8

Im trying to connect two nodes with a `CubicCurve` and want to track changes in the node to move the curve at the right place. It looks like this:

[image]

These `TitledPane`'s are draggable so I need to listen for position changes of the nodes. Since the curve is connected to these blue and green buttons the `layoutX` or `layoutY` properties of the buttons dont change when the parent is moved.

My question: is there a general way to listen for a position change of nodes or should I write a custom listener that is called when the `TitledPane` is moved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can listen to the [`localToSceneTransformProperty()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#localToSceneTransformProperty). Note that, as mentioned in the Javadocs, this listener will be notified if any of the node's parent's layout bounds are changed, so it's important to keep the code in the listener minimal in terms of computational expense.